# Can we use the TypeOrm for the RavenDB

Tags: nestjs, typeorm, ravendb

Can we use the TypeOrm for the RavenDB?

Any experiences?

there is a special **type** for Ravendb?

```
useFactory: async () => {
  const dataSource = new DataSource({
    type: 'ravendb',
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 3306,
    username: 'root',
    password: 'root',
    database: 'test',
    entities: [
        __dirname + '/../**/*.entity{.ts,.js}',
    ],
    synchronize: true,
  });
```